# Database not inserting and I cannot see why please check my code and report

Tags: php, forms, function, session, pdo

I have been pulling my hair out all day with this and have not found a solution to why this is not inserting into the db...It works fine locally but on the web server it does not, could someone please look at this code and see if you can see an error or any advice

Cheers

Function

```
public function Register($name, $email, $password)
{
    try {
        $db = DB();
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, password) VALUES (:name,:email,:password)");
        $query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $enc_password = hash('sha256', $password);
        $query->bindParam("password", $enc_password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        return $db->lastInsertId();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And this is my Register script

```
 $app = new SiteLib();
$register_error_message = '';
if (!empty($_POST['btnRegister'])) {
    if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
        $register_error_message = 'Name field is required!';
    } else if ($_POST['email'] == "") {
        $register_error_message = 'Email field is required!';
    } else if ($_POST['password'] == "") {
        $register_error_message = 'Password field is required!';
    } else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $register_error_message = 'Invalid email address!';
    } else if ($app->isEmail($_POST['email'])) {
        $register_error_message = 'Email is already in use!';
    } else {
        $user_id = $app->Register($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
       header("Location:frontpage.php");
       exit();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

EDIT:

This is the error

```
Warning: PDOStatement::setAttribute(): SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: This driver doesn't support setting attributes in /customers/3/c/2/er.co.uk/httpd.www/lib/library.php on line 10 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /customers/3/c/2/er.co.uk/httpd.www/lib/library.php:10) in /customers/3/c/2/preptracker.co.uk/httpd.www/register.php on line 25
```

This is line 10 of Library.php

```
$query->bindParam("name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

And this is line 25 of Register.php

```
header("location:frontpage.php");
```

hope this helps

Comment: Start by enabling error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and tell us what you get back.

Comment: Any special reason as to why you're using sha256 over `password_hash()`?

Comment: *"I have been pulling my hair out all day"* - Will we be waiting as long to get a report back as you asked? Asking about this type of question for debugging is off-topic.

Comment: different code, but same issue as your last post, how was that solved?